# duplicate entry "dailymaintenancelastdate" for key primary error

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I use cron to update a software database. Before it worked well but now nope.
see the image to see the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeiN3.png

before I had cron wurfl started and then finished
Now i have cron wurfl started and then i get the website error:
duplicate entry "dailymaintenancelastdate" for key primary

This is how looks config file for the database on phpmyadmin:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/doiLr.png

I need help to resolve this problemand thanks a lot

Comment: I think you have `Primary Key` constraint on `Name` field in `config` table. Remove that if you don't need it.

Comment: thank you. I removed it but I have now CRON WURFL job started and then CRON WURFL job started. I should get after CRON WURFL job started: CRON WURFL job finished.  any other solution?

Comment: There might be problem based on the way you have written your cron. The question does not clearly specifies what the problem is. I don't think it is happening because of primary key error.

Comment: thank you it worked well with the same cron so I don't think it's a cron structure problem. any other solution?